# MouseDrag on child widgets

Tags: qt

I am following [this instructions](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.de/2014/04/qt-get-child-controls-events.html) to get the child events. My aim is to change the value of QSpinBox by dragging the mouse up/down by keeping the Ctrl key pressed (like in GIMP).

However, while this works for the window, QSpinBox ignores the drag and just selects the contents inside.

I have installed the eventfilter into all childs with:

```
eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->type())
    {
        case QEvent::ChildAdded:
        {
            QChildEvent* ce = static_cast<QChildEvent*>(event);
            // Install the filter to each new child object created
            ce->child()->installEventFilter(this);
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::ChildRemoved:
        {
            QChildEvent* ce = static_cast<QChildEvent*>(event);
            // Remove the the filter from each new child object removed
            ce->child()->removeEventFilter(this);
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
        {
            QMouseEvent* me = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        qDebug() << QString::number(me->pos().x());
        qDebug() << QString::number(me->pos().y());
            return true;
        }
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        {
            QMouseEvent* me = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        qDebug() << QString::number(me->pos().x());
        qDebug() << QString::number(me->pos().y());
            return true;
        }
        case QEvent::MouseMove:
        {
            QMouseEvent* me = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        qDebug() << QString::number(me->pos().x());
        qDebug() << QString::number(me->pos().y());
            return true;
        }
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

and in the constructor using:

```
setMouseTracking(true);
installEventFilter(this);
```

How can I fully make QSpinBox ignore selection?

Comment: Could you elaborate "installed the eventfilter into all childs"?

Comment: @Bowdzone Thanks for interest. I used the `EventFilter` method above and used `InstallEventFilter(this)` to install those events. I think `ChildAdded` installs the `EventFilter` into the childs recursively. Am I wrong?